# How to get rid of xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" namespace on an element

Tags: saxon

I'm working on XSLT code I inherited from somebody else. It's using `<xsl:output method="html"/>` as output method. HTML elements are created as literals (e.g. `<html>` etc.). The problem is I can't get rid of the `xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"` namespace on the `<html>` element.

If I generate html element with `xsl:element` the namespace goes away, as expected, but then all the children have it and I just can't change all the literals to `xsl:element`, there are way too many, and the namespace doesn't actually make any harm. It's just that I'd like to find out if there's a way to remove it while keeping literals.

I've tried everything that came to my mind but nothing works. Why is this namespace even there? It's not supposed to be copied, for what I know, and you can't remove it with exclude-result-prefixes.

I'm using Saxon9-PE.

Comment: Sorry, all the tags disappeared. It's using <xsl:output method="html"/> as output method. HTML elements are created as literals, like <html>. The problem is I can't ger rid of the xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" namespace on the <html> element.

Comment: Edited to mark the elements as code, so they were not stripped out.

Comment: Before we can tell you how to get rid of this namespace declaration we need to know how/why it is getting into the output, and for that we need to see your code. Please supply a minimal reproducible example. I think the most likely explanation is that it's present on a source element that's being copied using xsl:copy or xsl:copy-of, but debugging code you can't see is a mug's game so that guess might be completely wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your tip, Michael (BTW, a great book and a great product). It'll be hard to create a minimal reproducible example since there are some 300 xsl files. However, I searched for all occurrences of the namespace and it only appears in the xsl:stylesheet. I did notice something potentially strange. A few files contain the following namespace as well:

Comment: xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/TransformAlias". For what I can see it's not used in code, not sure why it's there. Could this somehow be the culprit? I can't imagine why, but it's the only strange thing I've noticed while searching for http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform.

Comment: Got it:  in a file probably copied from who knows where (in 2006!), there's the following:  <xsl:stylesheet
 version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/TransformAlias"
 >
 <xsl:namespace-alias stylesheet-prefix="x" result-prefix="xsl"/>  and then   <xsl:template name="value-of">
  <xsl:param name="select"/>
  <xsl:param name="type" select="'string'"/>
  <x:value-of select="{$select}"/>
 </xsl:template>  it's the only place where it's used, probably due to copy&paste. Anyway, I'll fix it, thanks again for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

To answer my own question.

It was due to a namespace-alias. The following code was in one of the files:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
    version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:x="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/TransformAlias"
    >
    <xsl:namespace-alias stylesheet-prefix="x" result-prefix="xsl"/>
```

The code was probably copied from a 3rd party library and the alias remained (it was actually used in one element, don't have the faintest idea why).

Anyway, as soon as the alias was removed the namespace disappeared from the generated files. It's interesting to notice that it wasn't enough to fix the template that was using it. As long as the namespace-alias was there the namespace was generated.

I would never have thought to search for namespace-alias, I found it by shear luck when searching for all occurrences of the namespace in the code for anything strange :)

Comment: Indeed, I think that many XSLT experts would find that bug a tricky one to locate in a large stylesheet. One reason that XSLT packages were introduced in 3.0 was to enable people to write more modular code with less risk of global effects like this.